# Is there any method like max() function?

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I want to select the maximum value, but if the user has more than one value in one column, then leave all

I have a table :

```
create table package (U_id, service, offer,product) as
 select   1, 12345, null, null  from dual union all
select   1, null, 25468, null  from dual union all
select   1, null, null, 23456  from dual union all
select   2, 12345, 58889, null  from dual union all
select   2, 43456, null, null  from dual ;
```

I tried

```
select u_id, max(service), max(offer),max(product) 
from package
group by u_id
```

but, in the case of the second user, took only the maximum number from the service.

I want to get such a table:

| u_id | service | offer | product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 25468 | 23456 |
| 2 | 123456 | 58889 |  |
| 2 | 43456 |  |  |

Comment: Suppose a row `select  1, null, 77777, null  from dual union all` is added to sample data. What is the expected result?

Comment: As in the case of the second user. In the case of the first user, there will also be two  rows:  The first row is in the table and the second would be - u_id =1, service = null, offer = 77777 and product = null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use analytic functions to number the rows and then use conditional aggregation inside a `LATERAL` self-join to get the values into the correct rows:

```sql
WITH row_counts (
  u_id,
  service,
  offer,
  product,
  rn,
  service_rn,
  offer_rn,
  product_rn,
  num_rows
) AS (
  SELECT u_id,
         service,
         offer,
         product,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u_id ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rn,
         NVL2(service,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY u_id ORDER BY NVL2(service, ROWNUM, NULL) NULLS LAST
           ),
           NULL
         ) AS service_rn,
         NVL2(offer,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY u_id ORDER BY NVL2(offer, ROWNUM, NULL) NULLS LAST
           ),
           NULL
         ) AS offer_rn,
         NVL2(product,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY u_id ORDER BY NVL2(product, ROWNUM, NULL) NULLS LAST
           ),
           NULL
         ) AS product_rn,
         GREATEST(
           COUNT(service) OVER (PARTITION BY u_id),
           COUNT(offer)   OVER (PARTITION BY u_id),
           COUNT(product) OVER (PARTITION BY u_id)
         ) AS num_rows
  FROM   package
)
SELECT r.u_id,
       d.service,
       d.offer,
       d.product
FROM   row_counts r
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT MAX(CASE d.service_rn WHEN r.rn THEN d.service END) AS service,
                MAX(CASE d.offer_rn   WHEN r.rn THEN d.offer   END) AS offer,
                MAX(CASE d.product_rn WHEN r.rn THEN d.product END) AS product
         FROM   row_counts d
         WHERE  r.u_id = d.u_id
       ) d
WHERE  r.rn <= r.num_rows
ORDER BY r.u_id, r.rn;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE package (U_id, service, offer, product) AS
  SELECT 1, 12345, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL, 25468, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, NULL, NULL, 23456 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 12345, 58889, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 43456, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | U_ID | SERVICE | OFFER | PRODUCT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 12345 | 25468 | 23456 |
> | 2 | 12345 | 58889 | *null* |
> | 2 | 43456 | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=39a92043c6cfdd11d5b01dc338f706c9)*

---

In Oracle 11, you can use:

```sql
WITH row_counts (
  u_id,
  service,
  offer,
  product,
  rn,
  service_rn,
  offer_rn,
  product_rn,
  num_rows
) AS (
  SELECT u_id,
         service,
         offer,
         product,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u_id ORDER BY ROWNUM) AS rn,
         NVL2(service,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY u_id ORDER BY NVL2(service, ROWNUM, NULL) NULLS LAST
           ),
           NULL
         ) AS service_rn,
         NVL2(offer,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY u_id ORDER BY NVL2(offer, ROWNUM, NULL) NULLS LAST
           ),
           NULL
         ) AS offer_rn,
         NVL2(product,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY u_id ORDER BY NVL2(product, ROWNUM, NULL) NULLS LAST
           ),
           NULL
         ) AS product_rn,
         GREATEST(
           COUNT(service) OVER (PARTITION BY u_id),
           COUNT(offer)   OVER (PARTITION BY u_id),
           COUNT(product) OVER (PARTITION BY u_id)
         ) AS num_rows
  FROM   package
)
SELECT r.u_id,
       r.rn,
       MAX(CASE d.service_rn WHEN r.rn THEN d.service END) AS service,
       MAX(CASE d.offer_rn   WHEN r.rn THEN d.offer   END) AS offer,
       MAX(CASE d.product_rn WHEN r.rn THEN d.product END) AS product
FROM   row_counts r
       INNER JOIN row_counts d
       ON r.u_id = d.u_id
WHERE  r.rn <= r.num_rows
GROUP BY r.u_id, r.rn
ORDER BY r.u_id, r.rn
```

Which outputs:

> | U_ID | RN | SERVICE | OFFER | PRODUCT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 12345 | 25468 | 23456 |
> | 2 | 1 | 12345 | 58889 | *null* |
> | 2 | 2 | 43456 | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bebc6425d6d9ee0e5ddb2bbe2f066cda)*

Comment: I have an oracle version 11.1.0  and lateral function  does not work, only just take u_id and rest of column is null. The reason is the oracle version?

Comment: @user18552635 Updated with an Oracle 11g version. (And, yes, `LATERAL` was introduced in Oracle 12 so it is not supported in Oracle 11.)

Comment: @MTO   I tried the updated script for an Oracle 11, but that gave me the same result: only just take u_id and RN, and the rest of the column is null.  When I tried to run without a case statement, the service, the offer, and the product columns were not null,( But the result is wrong).  Maybe, such a case statement does not work in oracle 11?

Comment: @user18552635 The [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bebc6425d6d9ee0e5ddb2bbe2f066cda) in the question is for Oracle 11gR2 and shows it working in Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

This might be one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     package (U_id,
  3              service,
  4              offer,
  5              product)
  6     AS
  7        (SELECT 1, 12345, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
  8         UNION ALL
  9         SELECT 1, NULL, 25468, NULL FROM DUAL
 10         UNION ALL
 11         SELECT 1, NULL, NULL, 23456 FROM DUAL
 12         UNION ALL
 13         SELECT 2, 12345, 58889, NULL FROM DUAL
 14         UNION ALL
 15         SELECT 2, 43456, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL),
```

Query begins here: `temp` CTE calculates number of different `service`/`offer`/`product` values per each `u_id`; it is then checked against total number of rows per `u_id` in the `group by` clause so that query "knows" whether to group by those columns or not

```
 16     temp
 17     AS
 18        (  SELECT u_id,
 19                  COUNT (*) cnt,
 20                  COUNT (DISTINCT service) cnt_service,
 21                  COUNT (DISTINCT offer) cnt_offer,
 22                  COUNT (DISTINCT product) cnt_product
 23             FROM package
 24         GROUP BY u_id)
 25    SELECT p.u_id,
 26           MAX (p.service) service,
 27           MAX (p.offer) offer,
 28           MAX (p.product) product
 29      FROM package p JOIN temp t ON t.u_id = p.u_id
 30  GROUP BY p.u_id,
 31           CASE
 32              WHEN t.cnt <> t.cnt_service + t.cnt_offer + t.cnt_product
 33              THEN
 34                 p.service || p.offer || p.product
 35              ELSE
 36                 NULL
 37           END
 38  ORDER BY p.u_id;

      U_ID    SERVICE      OFFER    PRODUCT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1      12345      25468      23456
         2      12345      58889
         2      43456

SQL>
```

Comment: This gives an incorrect answer when you have columns with different values that concatenate together to give an identical value [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d27edea0198875a4c6787d194a66e61c)